# Remove Kubernetes Pod after a period of time

Tags: docker, kubernetes, cron, jobs, kubernetes-pod

Is it possible to remove a pod and service after a period of time? Say 24hrs, also there should be a capability to cancel the remove action if required. I believe it can be possible by using jobs, but not sure how it can be achieved, I have been reading about them, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a Job which executes and then removes itself after completion, that includes a sleep so that it lasts 24 hours.

You can create a Cronjob with kubectl access that deletes a pod with that selector every 24h, and then change the selector if you want to keep it.

I would just bundle it into a shell script that launches the pod, include a timer after it, and then a remove command. Just kill the process if you want to keep the pod.

Comment: Thanks, the total time limit is not exactly 24hrs, A user uses the pod and when he logs out, I got to wait for 24 hrs to remove that pod, but if he logs back in I need to restart the 24 hrs timer when he logs out. can’t remove when the user is using the pod, little bit complicated. I was thinking that I’ll normally launch a pod, then create a cron job when ever logout is clicked which sleeps for 24 hrs and removes the pod, and cancel if he relogs in does that work? Have never used cron with Kubernetes so I have no idea.

Comment: @Kowshhal that sounds more like you want your application to be a client of the kubernetes API. The application would manage the custom state logic then just send the delete pod request as it sees fit.